R connection to Amazon Redshift
I am getting an error when connecting to Amazon Redshift as follows:

rlang::last_trace()
<error/purrr_error_indexed>
Error in map():
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: all.
Caused by error in collect():
! Failed to collect lazy table.
Caused by error:
! nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1528: 08S01
[Amazon][Amazon Redshift] (20) Error occurred while trying to prepare a query: [SQLState 08S01] could not receive data from server: Software caused connection abort (0x00002745/10053)
SSL SYSCALL error: Software caused connection abort (0x00002745/10053)

Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─purrr::map(analysis_spec, ~run_analysis(included_pt, !!.x$strata), .progress = TRUE)
  2. │ └─purrr:::map_("list", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
  3. │   ├─purrr:::with_indexed_errors(...)
  4. │   │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
  5. │   ├─purrr:::call_with_cleanup(...)
  6. │   └─global .f(.x[[i]], ...)
  7. │     └─global run_analysis(included_pt, !!.x$strata)
  8. │       └─... %>% collect()
  9. ├─dplyr::collect(.)
 10. ├─dbplyr:::collect.tbl_sql(.)
 11. │ ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 12. │ ├─dbplyr::db_collect(...)
 13. │ └─dbplyr:::db_collect.DBIConnection(...)
 14. │   ├─DBI::dbSendQuery(con, sql)
 15. │   └─odbc::dbSendQuery(con, sql)
 16. │     └─odbc (local) .local(conn, statement, ...)
 17. │       └─odbc:::OdbcResult(...)
 18. │         └─odbc:::new_result(p = connection@ptr, sql = statement, immediate = immediate)
 19. └─base::stop(`<nndbc::_>`)   Can anyone help resolve? 

Checked connection to Con database which is fine but when running a query its not obtaining the data I Need.Thanks in advance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
